# How are addresses distributed in HDLC?

Tags: layer2

In an HDLC frame, the address field can be 8 bits, or extended according to what the first bit is. I know that `11111111` is a broadcast address, and that there are 2^7 possible addresses in an 8-bit address.

My question is: How are those addresses are distributed? Is there a random addressing or something live DHCP provided by HDLC?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, HDLC is actually vendor-dependent, and the HDLC implementation from one vendor is not compatible with HDLC implementation from another vendor.

> ...there is 2^7 possible addresses in 8bits address.

In an 8-bit address, there are 2^8 possible addresses, from `0` to `(2^8)-1`, or `0` to `255`.

> my question is how those addresses are distributed, is there a random
>   addressing or something live dhcp provided by hdlc?

You seem to be confusing things. DHCP is for layer-3 addressing, but HDLC is a layer-2 protocol. How each vendor assigns addresses is vendor-specific. For example, Cisco HDLC has two addresses: `10001111` and `00001111` for broadcast and unicast, respectively. The Cisco broadcast address only means that the layer-3 protocol has a broadcast address.